# file upload in iframe with karateui

Tags: karate

I am trying to upload file where form is in iframe.

main.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select file to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
    <iframe src="frame.html" id="uploadframe">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

frame.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select file to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.feature

```
Feature: file upload
  Scenario: file upload
    * driver '<path of main.html>'
    When switchFrame('#uploadframe')
    And driver.inputFile('#fileToUpload','test_file.pdf')
    Then switchFrame(null)
```

File is getting uploaded in form of main.html and not in iframe.
If I remove form in main.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="frame.html" id="uploadframe">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And run the test, I see this in log

```
13:39:07.288 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - << {"id":13,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"Could not find node with given id"}}
```

Is it possible to upload the file where form is in iframe?

Comment: please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test